# Cross-validation by hand in R

Tags: r, machine-learning, self-study

Trying to teach myself cross-validation on a super simple example, linear regression. My understanding is that when I build a model via CV, it should have a lower RMSE. But I find almost identical RMSEs with and without CV. Is this because I've coded too simple a problem? Or because I've implemented CV incorrectly?

Here is the code:

```
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(1234)
n = 1e4
x = rnorm(n) 
y = 1 + 3*x + rnorm(n)
df = data.frame(y,x)
df$id = 1:nrow(df)
df$train = sample(c(TRUE, FALSE), nrow(df), replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.7,0.3))
df_train = subset(df, train)
df_test = subset(df, !train)
k = 10 # 10 folds
df_train$fold = sample(rep(1:k, each = nrow(df_train)/k))

results = vector(mode = 'list', length = k)
for(i in 1:k){
  cv_train = df_train[df_train$fold != i,]
  cv_test = df_train[df_train$fold == i,]
  m = lm(y ~ x, data = cv_train)
  cv_test$y_resid = cv_test$y - predict(m, newdata = cv_test)
  results[[i]] = cv_test
  rm(cv_train, cv_test, m)
}
df2 = bind_rows(results)
rmse_by_fold = df2 %>% group_by(fold) %>% summarise(rmse = sqrt(mean(y_resid**2)))
# rmse
mean(rmse_by_fold$rmse)


# no cross validation
m = lm(y~x, data = df_train)
y_resid = df_train$y - predict(m, newdata = df_train)
# rmse
sqrt(mean(y_resid**2))
```

Comment: For a very simple linear model with two parameters, there may not be a difference between using 100 and 1000 data points since simple models work well with less data (bias-variance tradeoff)

Comment: Adding to @qwr's comment: yes, it is quite normal that a simple linear regression has comparable performance with and without cross-validation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> My understanding is that when I build a model via CV, it should have a lower RMSE. But I find almost identical RMSEs with and without CV. Is this because I've coded too simple a problem?

You've misunderstood the point of cross validation.  Cross validation does not *improve your model*.  Your model is not better for having done cross validation.  The technique is used to estimate the out of sample performance.

Let's see how this can be done in R without using a function from a library. Let's first begin my making a function which will sample from the true data generating process and then create a training set of 1000 samples.  We'll add a column called `fold` which will tell us which fold the observation belongs to, and hence when the observation will be left out.

```r
library(tidyverse)


make_data<-function(n){
  
  x = rnorm(n)
  y = 2*x + 1 + rnorm(n, 0, 1)
  tibble(x, y)
}


kfolds <- 10
train_n <-1000
train_data <- make_data(train_n) %>% 
              mutate(fold = sample(1:kfolds, size=train_n, replace=T))
```

We will now loop through each of the folds, leaving one out and training on the rest.  We will fit a model on the held out set and make predictions on the held out set.  We'll record the error in an array as we do the loop

```r
cv_err = rep(0, kfolds)
for(i in 1:kfolds){
  in_data <- filter(train_data, fold!=i)
  out_data <- filter(train_data, fold==i)
  
  fit <- lm(y~x, data = in_data)
  preds <- predict(fit, newdata=out_data)
  
  err <- out_data$y - preds
  mse <- mean(err^2)
  # Record the RMSE
  cv_err[i] <- sqrt(mse)
}
```

Out estimate is then just

```r
mean(cv_err)
# depending on your random seed
[1] 0.9908503
```

Which is pretty close to the standard deviation of the noise in the true data generating process (which is what RMSE estimates).  Because we simulated this, we can just take a big sample from the process and estimate the error.

```
test_data <- make_data(1e6)
fit <- lm(y~x, data = train_data)
preds <- predict(fit, newdata=test_data)
err <- test_data$y - preds
mse <- mean(err^2)
sqrt(mse)
# Depending on the random seed
[1] 1.001989
```

Note that the model did not improve after doing this procedure.  Our estimate is a good one (because we have correctly specified the conditional mean).

Answer (score 2):

There is a design flaw here: you are fitting the true model. To be precise, you simulated *(x, y)* from a straight line and fit a straight line. You will "perfectly" recover the truth, so you will observe that test error is about as same as training error.

Cross-Validation is used to combat overfitting. That is, you specify a model that is more complicated than the ground truth. For example, if the ground truth is a straight line but you train a quintic polynomial, then you will observe a small training error but a high test error.

When you have a sequence of candidate models, Cross-Validation can be used for model selection. Suppose the ground truth is a cubic polynomial, and you have 6 candidate models, namely polynomials of degree 1 to 6. Then you can compute a CV score for each choice of degree, and plot CV score against degree. You shall see that degree = 3 gives the minimal CV error.

Comment: "Cross-Validation is used to combat overfitting" -- this is a misleading statement.  Cross validation does not "combat" overfitting, it is a means of estimating the out of sample performance.  Use of the word "combat" suggests that the technique somehow improves the model, which underscores OP's misunderstanding.

Comment: @DemetriPananos You are talking about its definition (what it is). I am talking about its goal (why we care). BTY, your answer agrees with what I say. Fitting the true model to data gives optimal CV error, or, test error "=" training error. Isn't OP expect to see a higher test error but a low training error? Then fit a model that's more complicated than the truth.

Comment: I agree and understand what it is used for in practice, but OP seems to believe that CV improves the model (that the act of performing CV somehow changes the model for the better) *and that is wrong*.  I would suggest perhaps making that explicitly clear in your answer because -- as I read it -- your answer does not correct the misunderstanding and perhaps serves to bolster it.